# Jmeter after recording HTTPs site, on running those test cases, they all are failing

Tags: jmeter, http, test-script

I am able to record my test cases via Http(S) Test Script Recorder but when I run those test cases, they all are failing.
Before started recording, I was getting 'No Internet' message on my browser. But once I clicked on "Start' to record and refreshed my site,It started recording. After I am done with recording, Site is again not accessible with the same message 'No Internet' and failing my run. How can I make my site available again? I am using chrome browser.
Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like you have a proxy running for your recorder that's not stopping when you stop recording.  Might want to check your settings

Comment: How many Threads are created and what is the ramp-up period?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [HTTP Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is basically a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) which intercepts the requests from the browser to the application under test and records them in form of [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.

When you stop the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder the proxy server gets stopped as well therefore the browser cannot access the Internet, you need to go into your browser proxy settings and configure it to not to use JMeter as the proxy

[image]

More information: [How to set a proxy server in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge and Opera](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows)

You might also want to consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it right, your scenario is,

You set up Http(S) Test Script Recorder in Jmeter. This is a proxy recorder.

Hence, you would have configured the necessary proxy configuration in your browser.

You recorded your script and stopped the Http(S) Test Script Recorder.

But, you didn't reset the proxy configuration in your browser.

This would be the reason for the failures and the website not opening in the browser.

Reset the proxy configuration in your browser to default/no proxy and check whether the website opens or not.

Also to avoid all the hazel use [Blazemeter's Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en).

With this you can record your test script from the Chrome browser with any problem. It will also manage the cookies, sessions and certificates related stuff.

Once you've recorded your script you can download the JMX file. You can open this in Jmeter to make changes and run your tests.

To download JMX you may need to register and sign in with a free Blazemeter account.
I had listed the steps for recording and downloading the JMX file with Blazemeter [here](https://www.patelmilin.com/blog/testing/tools/performance-testing-with-jmeter.html). It may be helpful to you.